# How to dynamically generate HTML from JSON using AngularJs?

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm trying to make a general purpose JSON pretty-print using AngularJs.

For an idea what a prettyprinter is:  https://github.com/padolsey/prettyPrint.js

I'm not sure how to do this with angular,    I am guessing nested transcluded directives, but I am having problems getting nested transcludes to behave properly.  (For example: http://plnkr.co/edit/CHsGHCt3SU3N5MCJxwTV?p=preview )

If you could set me down a better path for dynamically generating html based on JSON (using Angular), I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the [angularTreeview](https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview/blob/master/angular.treeview.js) source to output the html you want

```
if( attrs.angularTreeview ) {

    //create tree object if not exists
    scope[treeId] = scope[treeId] || {};

    //if node head clicks,
    scope[treeId].selectNodeHead = scope[treeId].selectNodeHead || function( selectedNode ){

        //Collapse or Expand
        selectedNode.collapsed = !selectedNode.collapsed;
    };

    //if node label clicks,
    scope[treeId].selectNodeLabel = scope[treeId].selectNodeLabel || function( selectedNode ){

        //remove highlight from previous node
        if( scope[treeId].currentNode && scope[treeId].currentNode.selected ) {
            scope[treeId].currentNode.selected = undefined;
        }

        //set highlight to selected node
        selectedNode.selected = 'selected';

        //set currentNode
        scope[treeId].currentNode = selectedNode;
    };
}
```